# If the radius of a sphere is reduced by half due to relativistic length contraction, will the volume also be half?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry, spacetime-dimensions

We know that volume is cubicly proportional to radius of a sphere. But if  the radius is become half due to relativistic Length contraction, it's being reduced from only one dimension, not three. And the object is not a sphere any more .
Does it mean that the volume in that case is directly proportional to radius? And is density inversely proportional to the square of radius? (Since the mass is increasing by same multiple as the radius decreasing?

Comment: In the frame of the sphere, it happily remains a sphere with whatever density it has. From a different frame it may _appear_ to not be a sphere anymore, and one can calculate the apparent volume in such a situation.

Comment: And would that be directly proportional to radius ( which is not radius anymore)?

Comment: My intuition is that the sphere will appear to be an ellipsoid. If the sphere has radius $R$ in the rest frame, then in the lab frame the ellipsoid volume is $\frac43\,\pi R^2 c$, where $c$ is the axis along the direction of motion which has undergone an apparent length contraction.

Comment: Thanks,that make sense.

Comment: the real question is, is there an invariant volume $d^3xdt$?